# Get website from another host

Tags: php, curl, a-records

I want to get the content of a domain, but from a different host (IP) than specified in the current A-Records.

I've solved this using cURL:

```
$headers = array("Host: www.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$ip = "12.31.23.123";
$goto = "http://" . $ip . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$goto");
```

But i also need a way to get the images from the host!

Right now i only get the HTML code with cURL.

Any ideas?

Maybe a way to make the visitor download the image from the correct IP?

Comment: parse the HTML code for images and get them too

Comment: So i should "scan" the html code from cURL for images, get the URL and parse it to cURL to get them?
Do you have an example of such work? :)

Comment: have a look at the source code of any Web browser.

Comment: you can strip the image url from the page if you mean that